# Isotope fancybox gallery browsing error when using multiple filters.

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Im currently trying to figure out how to properly filter an isotope fancybox with jQuery. Essentially, I need to browse images in each filter independently from the main gallery browse. I have the main gallery with “all work" and when the first image is clicked it browses the entire gallery (thats fine).

When choosing my list of other filters i.e. client work, it properly takes away any images not assigned to that filter. But when browsing to the next image in my client work filter it shows and continues to browse images as if it were the main gallery. I would like to be able to only browse images in that filter.

Aside from my endless hours of research, I managed to get some good information but I still can’t quite understand what to change in jQuery because it’s all very new to me. I would appreciate any insight to my question, as this is the final hurdle in the completion of my site.

I attached a link to a gallery that has the filtering and browsing exactly how I need it. (I read the info from that site, but got lost in what to keep from the existing code and what not to keep.

http://www.picssel.com/demos/fboxfilteredgallery.html

Thanks in Advance

Here is a portion of my html:

```
<!-- Portfolio Projects -->
    <div class="row">       
            <div class="span3">             
             <!-- Filter -->
            <nav id="options" class="work-nav">
                <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">ALL WORK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".client">Client</a></li>                   
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".personal">Personal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".video">Video</a></li>

                 </ul>
            </nav>
```

```
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                          <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="JB Homes" href="_include/img/work/full/logo_full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                          <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/logo_thumb.jpg" alt=“Lorem Ipsum”>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 client">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="March of Dimes-Latin Fusion" href="_include/img/work/full/mod_full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>

                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/mod_thumb.jpg" alt=“Lorem Ipsum">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->                       


                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 personal">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Go Green" href="_include/img/work/full/green_full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/green_thumb.jpg" alt=“Lorem Ipsum”>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->


                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 client">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="March of Dimes-Princeton" href="_include/img/work/full/mod2_full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/mod2_thumb.jpg" alt=“Lorem Ipsum”>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->                              

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 personal">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Apple 3D" href="_include/img/work/full/apple_full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/apple_thumb.jpg" alt=“Lorem Ipsum”>
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
BRUSHED.filter = function (){
if($('#projects').length > 0){      
    var $container = $('#projects');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
          // options
          animationEngine: 'best-available',
          itemSelector : '.item-thumbs',
          layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });
    });



// filter items when filter link is clicked
    var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

}

Comment: The link to the gallery you provided doesn't use Isotope but a custom jQuery filtering method. The tutorial is here http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox/ On the other hand, if you want to use fancybox with Isotope, then check https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fancybox/ncVsViD2v9o/JE0DHYPuEOgJ

Comment: Thanks for responding JFK, my site is using fancybox w/ Isotope. I guess my problem is finding the error in the existing code (which is a template), to see what is causing the filters to not browse independently from the main gallery when those said filters are selected.

Comment: And if I am following your google link correctly does that mean I would be deleting the information from (//filter items when filter link is clicked)and down then replacing it with the code you provided?